# Not able to add an extra column to existing model in django

Tags: django, migration

I deleted migrations folder and now i am not able to add an additional column to the existing model. I assume it is because i deleted the migrations folder.
What is the fix for this? I am using django1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume it is because i deleted the migrations folder

You assume correctly. If you have version control, rollback the deletion and its fine.

Otherwise you will probably need to resync the database from scratch.